vite cannot connect to dev server via discord activity
Vite cannot connect to the development server backend because discord's CSP says everything other than the page has to use .proxy/.
here are the 2 rules in there:
https://<id>.discordsays.com/.proxy/
wss://<id>.discordsays.com/.proxy/

I searched for how to configure Vite to do this, but i have found nothing.
